# Error with IPython 4 shell using Sublime REPL

Tags: python, ipython, sublimetext3, jupyter, sublimerepl

I'm having trouble running IPython with sublime text REPL package. I'm using Python 3.5 and Jupyter Console 4.1.1.

```
Jupyter Console 4.1.1

Jupyter Console 4.1.1
C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\python.EXE: Error while finding spec for 'ipykernel.__main__' (<class 'ImportError'>: Module use of python33.dll conflicts with this version of Python.); 'ipykernel' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

Comment: How did you install SublimeREPL? Did you make any changes to the configuration at all, including making any custom settings or editing any of the default settings? Do you have `jupyter`, `ipython`, and all of their dependencies installed?

Comment: I didn't make any changes. All the dependences were installed but I managed to solve it from this post. https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/140 Turns out Sublime Text current directory was set to the Sublime Text 3 home dir.

Comment: yeah, I wondered if that might have been the case. Glad you got it working!